# How to hide pdf file from user in android device?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I am building a React native application and I want to hide some PDF files that are coming from API and want to download those files just like YouTube does when you download the video so that no one can find them on the phone.

Also, I want access to the downloaded file.
When user is offline, user can open that file in the app.

Issue link -  https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/issues/802

Comment: Use getFilesDir() and/or getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: How to use this in react native ?